# Python, Tkinter: How to get coordinates on scrollable canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, coordinates

I have a Tkinter canvas with a scrollbar, and some items that when I click them, it's supposed to return the coordinates. (Using Python.)

This works fine with the objects that's initially visible in the window. When I scroll down, however, and the items further down on the canvas come into view, I don't get their canvas coordinates when clicking, but the window coordinates.

I can't find info on how to get the absolute coordinates, so I'm wondering if anyone here knows how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the documentation for the canvas widget [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#coordinate-systems).

> To convert from window coordinates to canvas coordinates, use the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods.

Here is an example callback function which converts the window's x and y coordinates and prints the item closest to that position via the `find_closest()` [method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method).

```
def callback(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    print canvas.find_closest(x, y)
```

Comment: If the image is smaller than the canvas, then the above method gives me the absolute canvas co-ordinates, and not the co-ordinates of the image. Is there any way I can get the smaller image to fill the canvas or resize the canvas to display the image without any borders?